# Datagrid's hyperlink linkin a child table's column

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview

I have two tables linked. Mother table Versions and Child table Files.
Versions has column called fileID that links with ID column from Files. Files has a column called Url that is the column I want to retrieve. So the problem is that if I do "DataNavigateUrlFields="File.Url" the system drops a not found error. I can use Version.File.Url in the code behind without problem.

How can I do it?

it is the code (I have erased annoying code):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" >
    <Columns>
      <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="File.Url" 
       DataNavigateUrlFormatString="download.aspx?id={0}" HeaderText="Descargar" 
       Text="Documento" />
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>

<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="QDoc.Class.LinqToSql.QDocDataContext" TableName="Versions" 
    Where="DocId == @DocId">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="DocId" QueryStringField="id" 
            Type="Int32" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `File.Url` with a property.
Guessing your `Version` class is generated and hence declared `partial`. So, you can define a property inside `Version` like this:

```
partial class Version
{
   public string FileUrl
   {
      return File.Url;
   }
}
```

And you can use this like:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="FileUrl" 
       DataNavigateUrlFormatString="download.aspx?id={0}" HeaderText="Descargar" 
       Text="Documento" />
```